# AngularJS: Using third party libraries without exposing a global variable

Tags: angularjs

What is the best way to use a third party library in Angular without exposing a global variable?

For instance, if I were using underscore.js, I want to inject _ into only the controllers that use it.

```
angular.module('module').controller(function(_) {
  // _ is injected only into this scope
};
```

To get this effect, I've seen some people load underscore globally with a script tag, then create a service like this:

```
myModule.factory('_', function ($window) {
    return $window._;
});
```

However, this still pollutes the global scope with _.

Is there an 'Angular way' of registering and injecting third party libraries without causing this problem?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can't do anything about how the third party libraries are written, except by forking them and creating your own version.

Third party libraries will almost always create such variables on the global scope, and you mention the two most frequently used ways of using them in an Angular module: by injecting `$window` and using them directly, or by creating a thin `service` which provides the object.

I would favor the latter in most cases because it makes the code in other modules simpler. Also, in my mind, the service approach makes the code in your controllers seem less 'magic' and more debuggable, as it is clear where the library, e.g. `_` comes from. Variables appearing "out of thin air" is some of the problem with global variables to begin with.

The library will still "pollute" the global scope, unless you explicitly deletes them from the global scope, perhaps after fetching a pointer to them in a service, which then can pass it on. However, I can't see any motivation for doing so. Any other attempts, such as using an Angular service to actually download the third party script and evaluating it, somehow preventing it from reaching the global scope, seems vastly inefficient, over-engineered and slow (both computationally and with regards to when HTTP requests are fired).

It's otherwise a good idea not to create any more global variables than strictly necessary.

Answer (score 5):

For third party libraries that support provide a `noConflict` function - such as [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#noConflict) and [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) - you could use that to prevent global pollution in your Angular factory.

```
myModule.factory('_', ['$window', function ($window) {
   var underscore = $window._.noConflict();

   return underscore;
}]);
```

Since all services in Angular are singletons it means that the injector uses each recipe at most once to create the object. The injector then caches the reference for all future needs.

Answer (score 5):

Put third party libraries in angular constants. 
Keeps your code readable and clean and you can inject them in the specific controllers, directives,... where you want to use them.

```
angular
      .module('sampleApp', [])
      .constant('_', window._)
      .constant('$', window.$)
```

As documented in [John Papa's style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#style-y240) *[credits to @MaximilianoBecerra]*

Comment: It seems to be the right way to go, is documented on the angularjs styleguide: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#style-y240.

Comment: @MaximilianoBecerra Can't see if you have done it already or not but upvoting is a good way to state the correctness of the answer. 
Is it ok if I add the link from the styleguide to my answer?

Comment: @ tdhulster I've already upvoted and I think that yes because there you can find the full reference of what, why and how to  :)

Answer (score 4):

Miike is right, you can't "stop" a module from doing badness. Once anything calls window.whatever = ...

Require.js though is cool as async module definition library/methodology which helps people who are building packages do it without mucking in the global namespace. It won't help offenders, but it's neat.

http://requirejs.org/

Comment: If the 3rd party library provides a `noConflict` option, then you may use that to remove variables from the global scope (as per [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25400627/808278)).

Answer (score 2):

I've created a tool which will create an angular factory rather than a global for all libraries that support require js.  Since most libraries support require.js, I was able to write a function which mimics require's 'define' function, but rather than adding the library to require, it adds it as an angular injectable.  It is practically `plug n' play`.  Just include the js source after jQuery and angular and you're good to go.  It's called angular global injector and available on github.  Here's the link: https://github.com/btesser/angular-global-injector